Azure SqlTrigger function hardcoded table name issue
I implemented SqlTrigger function. It works with hardcoded schema and tableName.
[Function("SqlTriggerFunction")]
public async Task AFunction([SqlTrigger("[schema].[TableName]", "SqlConnectionString")] IReadOnlyList<SqlChange<TableObject>> changes)
{
...
}

The challenge is that different environments have different db schema name.
I would expect that I could use "%tableName%" stored in Values of app settings.
But I got an exception:
A host error has occurred during startup operation ''.
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Sql: Encountered error(s) while parsing schema and object name:
Incorrect syntax near %.
Do some know how to set table name for the SqlTrigger attribute from config or runtime?

please check if the solution below helps you. Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.

I found the solution to the issue. We could not specify schema in SQLTrigger attribute at all. But what is important here is to use db user with default desired db schema.

The tablename cannot be passed as dynamic value for default SQL trigger Azure function but it works only in case of  input and output binding.
Input Binding:
You can pass SQL tablename as a parameter for SQL Triggered Azure function with Input binding.
local.settings.json:
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<storage_connection_string>",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "schema": "dbo",
    "SqlConnection": "<SQl_connection_string>",
    "tableName": "<sql_tablename>"
  }
}

Function code:
 [FunctionName("GetToDoItem")]
 public static IActionResult Run(
     [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "gettodoitem")]
     HttpRequest req,
     [Sql(commandText: "select * from %schema%.%TableName% where Id = @Id",
         commandType: System.Data.CommandType.Text,
         parameters: "@Id={Query.id}",
         connectionStringSetting: "SqlConnection")]
     IEnumerable<ToDoItem> toDoItem)
 {
     return new OkObjectResult(toDoItem.FirstOrDefault());
 }

Console Output:
Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.5801 Commit hash: N/A +5ac2f09758b98257e728dd1b5576ce5ea9ef68ff (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.34.1.22669

[2024-06-06T08:28:28.766Z] Found C:\Users\uname\Source\Repos\FunctionApp\FunctionApp.csproj. Using for user secrets file configuration.

Functions:

        GetToDoItem: [GET] http://localhost:7136/api/gettodoitem

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-06-06T08:28:43.044Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-06-06T08:29:03.173Z] Executing 'GetToDoItem' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=8dc73db0-106e-42f1-a13d-7e9cc3392a06)
[2024-06-06T08:29:03.324Z] Executed 'GetToDoItem' (Succeeded, Id=8dc73db0-106e-42f1-a13d-7e9cc3392a06, Duration=24342ms)


Could fetch the values by fetching the tablename value from local.settings.json:


